# Magento 2 Mailchimp Abadoned cart email not working

Tags: magento2, database, cron, table, mailchimp

In the current Using version we are using Magento 2.4.

We are Using this Mailchimp Magento extension - https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html

We upgraded the Magento version from 2.3.5-p2 to 2.4 before Mailchimp Abandoned cart email is working fine when we upgrade the Magento version then it is not working fine.

As we checked the database table `cron_schedule` found that

job_code `ebizmarts_ecommerce`

status is `error` and

message is

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to 
    user 'xyz'@'xxx.xx.xx.xxx' for table '3', query was: 
    SELECT `main_table`.*, `m4m`.* FROM `newsletter_subscriber` AS 
    `main_table` LEFT JOIN `xyz_2`.`3` AS `m4m` ON m4m.related_id = 
    main_table.subscriber_id and m4m.type = 'SUB' and 
    m4m.mailchimp_store_id = 'b667cba572de' WHERE (`subscriber_status` = 
    1) AND (`main_table`.`store_id` = 1) AND (m4m.mailchimp_sync_delta IS
     null OR (m4m.mailchimp_sync_delta > '' and 
    m4m.mailchimp_sync_modified = 1)) LIMIT 100"
```

where XYZ is my database username and xxx.xx.xx.xxx is IP

Another cron is working fine.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?